# How can you use square brackets in tikz diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to draw a sequence in TeX with Tikz where the vertices are $[X,Y]$, however I can't seem to get the code to work. Here is the code I am trying to use.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
The retract of an $E$-local spectrum is $E$-local.
\end{prop}
\begin{proof}
Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of spectra with $Y$ an $E$-local spectrum so
that $f$ admits a retract. Thus, there is $r:Y\to X$ such that $rf=1$. Then for $Z$ an $E$-acyclic spectrum we get a diagram whose composite is the identity
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
 [Z, X]\arrow{r}{f_*}& [Z, Y]\arrow{r}{r_*}& [Z, X]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
but as $Y$ is $E$-local, $[Z, Y]=0$. So, in fact $[Z, X]=0$.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Z' (in `Z').
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. Use of `\left [ ... \right ]` instead.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
The retract of an $E$-local spectrum is $E$-local.
\end{prop}
\begin{proof}
Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of spectra with $Y$ an $E$-local spectrum so
that $f$ admits a retract. Thus, there is $r:Y\to X$ such that $rf=1$. Then for $Z$ an $E$-acyclic spectrum we get a diagram whose composite is the identity
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\left [Z, X \right]\arrow{r}{f_*}& \left [Z, Y\right ]\arrow{r}{r_*}&\left [Z, X\right ]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
but as $Y$ is $E$-local, $[Z, Y]=0$. So, in fact $[Z, X]=0$.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although this method works for the nodes themselves (as in the OP's question here) @user11232's answer works for both nodes and arrow labels.

Answer (score 27):

`[` has a special purpose in `tikz`. The options to `tikz` commands are enclosed within `[..]`. You can hide `[` (and `]`) from `tikz` parser by enclosing it(them) within braces like `{[Z, X]}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{prop}
The retract of an $E$-local spectrum is $E$-local.
\end{prop}
\begin{proof}
Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of spectra with $Y$ an $E$-local spectrum so
that $f$ admits a retract. Thus, there is $r:Y\to X$ such that $rf=1$. Then for $Z$ an $E$-acyclic spectrum we get a diagram whose composite is the identity
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
 {[Z, X]}\arrow{r}{f_*}& {[Z, Y]}\arrow{r}{r_*}& {[Z, X]}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
but as $Y$ is $E$-local, $[Z, Y]=0$. So, in fact $[Z, X]=0$.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]